# Debugging AngularJS Framework

Tags: angularjs, debugging

I am trying to understand how AngularJS framework works. For that reason I want to debug angularjs framework code (not my application code) however I am not able to figureout how angular gets attached to DOM and starts compilation. Can anybody help me to findout which is piece of code or lines in angularjs script file from where AngularJS kicks off and starts parsing and compilation.

Comment: Actually, if you really want to know the exact point of time, I think it should be that: 1. `angular.js` get loaded; 2. AngularJS parses your html and find the `ng-app` attribute; 3. AngularJS tries to find the module defined in `ng-app` and bootstrap that.

Answer (score 3):

you need to read the application bootstrap section in the angular docs, but basically angular will take your html, starts the compilation processes, at which point it will start replacing any custom html or directives with the matching templates, no scopes or bindings done just yet, html might not even be in dom yet, afer that angular goes to linking process, where bindings are made, scopes are created and  html gets attached to DOM, thats the short version you can find it here

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Comment: Thanks Dayan. I Will check it out however I am interested to know which is very first line or function in angularjs script file where angularjs kicks off.